# Calculating a perpendicular 3d vector in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I've got two 3d vectors, 90 degrees apart if seen from above. They are of different lengths and different angles (as deltaY is random while deltaX and deltaZ are constants). Now I want a vector perpendicular to these ( n in the 3D plane function ).

I am doing this in a custom library with Javascript, I do not have access to Math.CrossProduct() or Math.Dot()

Comment: Have you tried implementing CrossProduct and Dot yourself?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. If you need help with the math you may be better off asking on another site. If you need help with the code please update the question with what you have tried and what the problem is - we are here to help, not write code upon request.

Comment: Sure traktor53. I'm not looking for code, just a brief explanation on 3D vectors for a layman. And yes, maybe I'm better off asking somewhere else.